# How to work with Mercurial fork parent repository?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

For example exists `hg` rep **A** - project setup environment. It contains following files:

```
//project A
.some_config_file
script_1
```

After project **B** forked from *A*, some changes was made.

```
// project B
M .some_config
M script_1
```

Parallel in project **A** there has been improved some features or bug fixed in `script_1`.

```
// project A
M script_1
```

When I try to pull new features (`hg pul -u 'repA'`) to **B** from **A**, it brings old `.some_config` back to repository and overwrites actual one.

And there is my questions:

**How do I resolve this conflicts?**

**How to pull partially changes from fork parent?**

**And what the best practice to work with fork parent?**

Pulling from forked rep, pollutes local one.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be unfamiliar with the distinction of your 'working copy' and the repository as a tree of individual changesets.

The solution likely is: update your working copy to your fork B. Then merge the original project, fork A, into your currently checked-out version, into fork B. Take care to only accept those changes during the merge which you want to be merged - and discard any changes made to .some_config

Besides that, it's often a bad idea to have config files in a repo. Only have *example* config files there (and name them such) and keep the actual config file outside, untracked.

Comment: config does not contain secure information, it is just basic project properties and example is fictional

Comment: I did something like you said, but there is a problem. Both projects got **dev** and **master** branches. When I pulling **A** **master** branch to **B** it messes with my local rep **master**. I have to merge master and dev, it becomes a mess. Is there any way to omit this, is it possible to pull to a *certain* separate branch that represents master branch of parent rep?

Comment: you can explicitly give a branch name to the push or push command

Comment: how? I can pull certain branch like `hg pull -r master parent_rep` but how to save it as for example **parent** branch?

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment's question. Check `hg help pull`... a commit has *always* the information which branch it belongs to. Thus if you tell a command to only push/pull/whatever 'master', it does so. Try pulling without updating your working copy... that's mercurial's default, unless you overwrite that or use some tool which does.